# Selection on Lookup to display name on UI and select RecId ax 2012

Tags: axapta, lookup, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-ax-2012, dynamics-ax-2012-r3

I have unbound field on a form. Right now i am showing a look-up on that field using a look-up method which shows All distinct values from a field in a table. Now i changed that name field in table to Recid field. Now i need to display look-up with names but when i select one value i want to show name on U I but i have to select Recid. I don't want recid to display in look-up.  How can i achieve that?

Before i used to get lookup of name  using this method like this

public void lookup()
{

```
SysTableLookup       sysTableLookup =   SysTableLookup::newParameters(tablenum(RTTable), this);
Query                query = new Query();
QueryBuildDataSource queryBuildDataSource;
;

sysTableLookup.addLookupfield(fieldnum(RTTable, AsstManager));
queryBuildDataSource = query.addDataSource(tablenum(RTTable));
queryBuildDataSource.addSortField(fieldnum(RTTable, AsstManager));
queryBuildDataSource.addRange(fieldNum(RTTable, AsstManager)).value(queryNotValue(''));
queryBuildDataSource.orderMode(ordermode::GroupBy);
sysTableLookup.parmQuery(query);
sysTableLookup.performFormLookup();

super();
```

}

Answer (score 2):

You need `.addSelectionField(...)`, and most likely to remove the `super()` line.

See these links for some examples:

https://daxbeginners.wordpress.com/tag/lookup-table/

http://dynamicsuser.net/forums/p/56634/303103.aspx

Ah, I forgot also you can specify the return field in the optional second argument of:
`sysTableLookup.addLookupfield(fieldnum(RTTable, AsstManager), TRUE);`

See second argument at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/systablelookup.addlookupfield.aspx

Comment: .addSelectionfield() doesnot work. I tried with addSelectionfield for AsstMgrID but eventhough its UI and backend its taking the AsstMgr name only. I need on UI the name and on backend its ID to be used.

Comment: This is a standard feature of AX 2012. Your RecId has to be used as a surrogate key and the field you want to display as the replacement key. As it's an unbound field, you have to set the link on the EDT. So create a new Int64 EDT extanding RefRecId and set it to refer to your table.

Comment: Can you explain little clearly. I am confused. Recid has to be used a surrogate key means? (Do i need to give ASstMgrRecid field in table as PrimaryIndex for that table?)  THe field ASSTmgrName which i want to display should be used in Replacement key?   I need to create EDT and use it for the unbound field?

Comment: See this for Surrogate keys: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh812105.aspx
And this: https://community.dynamics.com/ax/b/axrajdipdas/archive/2013/04/16/how-to-create-and-implement-of-surrogate-keys-in-ax2012

Comment: Hi I  used form lookup and achieved this.

Comment: I just updated the answer with some more information. You have to set the 2nd parameter to "true" to set the return item.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by having a custom lookup form and using the CloseSelect() method on the form. There you can put in the code to return your recId